# Beginner: Doesn't understand where's the mistake of my code

Tags: python-3.x

I start learning python since yesterday , I tried to code myself after learning some basics. I can't go on if I haven't understood the basics.
Take a look at my code and explain to me about my mistake please.

```
x=input()
if(x==10):
    print("the number is 10")
    elif(x>=10):
        print("the number is more than 10")
        else:
            print("the number is less than 10")
```

---

```
 File "..\Playground\", line 4
    elif(x>=):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You don't have something to compare `x` to in your `elif`.  Also, you should read some more about the basics of Python programming.  It's indent delimited so your code is never going to act as you expect.

Comment: I see, but is there any more mistake beside that?

Comment: I'll defer to the answers below, specifically by Netwave as that is the specific code you would want to use for your particular problem.

Comment: Yes , thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a string, but you want an `int`, also your identation is quite wrong:

```
x=int(input())
if(x == 10):
    print("the number is 10")
elif(x >= 10):
    print("the number is more than 10")
else:
    print("the number is less than 10")
```

Comment: @JunSheng, you are welcome. Since you are pretty new you may consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Happy coding!